# Can I change my name?

Tags: spiral-knights

I've been told that "John the Green" sounds better than "John The Green Guy", and I'm inclined to agree.

But, I've already made my knight, and I named him "Johnthegreenguy" (no spaces allowed.  **:(** )

Can I change my name? If so, how?

Comment: If you do make a new character or happen to get a name change, you can make "spaces" using hyphens. It will allow you to capitalize the next letter after it. I Wish I knew this before I made my character...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now possible with a [Name Change Pass](http://wiki.spiralknights.com/Name_Change_Pass) which can be purchased in the Supply Depot for 3,500 energy.

Answer (score 3):

According to various forums, there is no way to change your name (short of it being considered offensive somehow, and thereby getting it force-changed to something generic).

Some people have claimed that if you ask a GM nice and politely, they might change the name for you, but I haven't been able to find any confirmation of that ever actually happening.

It would seem that your only real course of action is to start over from scratch with a new character with a different name, unfortunately.